# Passport login not calling the function in strategy file

Tags: node.js, passport.js, nestjs

I am trying to use **Passport** for **SSO**. My problem is that when I log in with any of the options everything is fine, except the `data saving`... I think the `functions` in the `strategy` files are not called (the log is not working neither).

For example the `Google strategy`:

```
@Injectable()
export class GoogleStrategy extends PassportStrategy(Strategy, 'google') {
  constructor(private userService: UserService) {
    super({
      clientID: GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID,
      clientSecret: GOOGLE_CLIENT_SECRET,
      callbackURL: 'http://localhost:4200',
      scope: ['email', 'profile'],
    });
  }

  async validate(
    accessToken: string,
    refreshToken: string,
    profile: any,
    done: VerifyCallback,
  ): Promise<any> {
    try {
      console.log(profile);
      const user = profile;
      this.userService.FindOrCreate(profile);
      done(null, user);
    } catch (err) {
      done(err, null);
    }
  }
}
```

Controller:

```
@Get('google')
  @UseGuards(AuthGuard('google'))
  async twitterauth(@Req() req) {
    return await this.authService.login(req.user);
  }
```

AuthService:

```
@Injectable()
export class AuthService {
  private readonly logger = new Logger(AuthService.name);
  constructor(
    private userService: UserService,
    private readonly jwtService: JwtService,
  ) {}

  async validateUser(email: string, password: string): Promise<User> {
    const user: User = await this.userService.findOne({
      where: { email },
    });
    if (!user) {
      return null;
    } else {
      if (await bcrypt.compare(password, user.password)) {
        return user;
      } else {
        this.logger.error('Password is incorrect.');
        return null;
      }
    }
  }

  async login(user: any) {
    const payload = { email: user.email, role: user.role };
    return {
      // eslint-disable-next-line @typescript-eslint/camelcase
      access_token: this.jwtService.sign(payload),
    };
  }
}
```

The other strategies (fb, linkedin, instagram, github) are quite the same and the problem is the same.

Comment: Why are you instantiating a new `Strategy` yourself and not making a class that extends Nest's `PassportStrategy`? If you're using `AuthGuard()`, you should be [following Nest's documentation](https://docs.nestjs.com/techniques/authentication)

Comment: @JayMcDoniel I have updated the post with the style of strategy you advised. The problem is still the same... :(

Comment: I'm noticing you have your callback url to `http://localhost:4200`. Do you have a server running at that port, and does it's base route handle Google's callback to your server?

Comment: Yes it does and the redirect is working fine.

Comment: And it's the same server? Cause that's where the saving logic will be taking place. On the callback route

Comment: Both of them are local

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/221333/discussion-between-jay-mcdoniel-and-g-mark11).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem, as found in chat, was that the callback that Google was calling to in the OAuth flow, was not a part of the same server, and as such, the NestJS server could not react to the incoming data, hence why the `validate` was never called.

> That callback route needs to point to your NestJS server so that it can handle the saving logic for the database,**OR** the angular applications needs to re-route the return to it back to the NestJS server. Either way, your validations aren't being called because your Nest server never gets the callback with all the sensitive information from Google

> More than likely, it will be better to have the callback pointed at your server so that the data is formatted as Passport is expected.